# HTML5 Canvas using easeljs pan

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, easeljs

Does anyone here have a good example of panning using Easeljs?  I am actually animating a ball inside a large canvas, about 5200x7400.  I am able to center the ball on the screen using a div that contains the canvas, setting it to overflow scroll and then using the function `tick()` to set the `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` of my `<div>`.

I just want to do this using pure canvas because when I try to use my site on Android 4.0, `scrollTop` and `ScrollLeft` don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are using such a large canvas, instead of just moving the contents within the canvas? A big canvas like that will have quite a huge impact on memory and performance - whereas translating a Container inside the canvas is fairly insignificant.

Comment: it's actually a City map with high details, i would also love to try dividing the map data into tiles but i haven't tried yet

Comment: The city map is only stored as a Jpeg file and is just loaded in CSS, would it be also better if i load the background map via EaselJs as a child?

Comment: Yeah i recommend loading the image, and then breaking it up into sectors (shapes), then moving those sectors in corresponding to a camera position. If you need an example let me know.